# How to set the region (selection) programmatically in Emacs Lisp using indices?

Tags: region

Given 2 absolute numbers (compatible with `region-beginning`, `region-end`).

How can these numbers be used to set the selection?

---

*Edit: If you use evil mode you may want to check [this question](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/34890), at the time of asking I wasn't aware this required a different method in some cases.*

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The region is defined as the span of text between point and mark, therefore it's sufficient to adjust both to the numbers in question.  The following uses `point-min` and `point-max` for that purpose:

```
(set-mark (point-min))
(goto-char (point-max))
```

However you mention "set the selection" afterwards, so perhaps you don't only want to change the region (as there is always a region), but activate it as well:

```
(activate-mark)
```

Comment: Maybe worth mentioning that `(setq deactivate-mark nil)` may need to be set in some cases *(as you found when looking into why setting selection sometimes fails)*.

Comment: Not really as activating the mark works, it's just that it's deactivated right afterwards. This is therefore material for a new question of the "Why is mark deactivated after a <...> command?" kind.