# How to set the evil-visual-line region (selection) programmatically in Emacs Lisp using indices?

Tags: evil, region

Given 2 absolute numbers (compatible with region-beginning, region-end).

How can these numbers be used to set the evil-mode line visual selection?

(note, I originally asked [this question](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/34873/how-do-i-set-the-region-selection-programmatically-in-emacs-lisp-using-indices/34874#34874), but found its not compatible with evil-visual-line-mode)

---

[This page](https://www.reddit.com/r/emacs/comments/6opc9l/evil_bug_applymacrotoregionlines_does_not_work/) looks like it's the same issue, but the solution doesn't apply here AFAICS.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Evil offers two functions for creating regions, `evil-visual-select` and `evil-visual-make-selection`.  You'll want the former as it accepts two locations, whereas the latter accepts values for point and mark.  The following creates a visual line selection from point to end of buffer:

```
(evil-visual-select (point) (point-max) 'line)
```